# Adding more Chart Series Dynamically to existing DataVisualization.Chart

Tags: c#, windows, charts, data-visualization

I have a `System.Windows.Form` application that uses `DataVisualization.Chart`. I have it correctly displaying candlestick charts. That series is hardwired using the Visual Studio properties page. That series is set to XValueIndexed.

Then, I want to dynamically add new series. Those series represent a line across each (intra) day from beginning of day to close of day, that represents where that day Opened across the intraday candles. When I try to do this, I get an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll

Additional information: Cannot display indexed series (XValueIndexed = true)
on the same axis if they are not aligned.Series 'USDCAD' and Series '9/9/2015'
must be aligned to perform the operation. The series currently have a different
number of data points.
```

If I understand this correctly, it wants me to add all the points between the two lines. But that is silly. Two points determine a line?

```
public uint GetYYYYMMDDFromDateTime(System.DateTime dt)
{
    uint retVal = (uint)(dt.Year + (10000 * dt.Month) + (1000000 * dt.Day));

    return retVal;
}

public void PaintChart()
{
    DateTime dt;

    RunOnUIThread(() =>
    {
        historicalChart.Series[0].Points.Clear();

        List<HistoricalDataMessage> historicalData = ibg.HistoricalData();
        Dictionary<uint, DayBarOpenClose> chartDateIndexDict = new Dictionary<uint, DayBarOpenClose>();

        System.DateTime lastDt = System.DateTime.MinValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < historicalData.Count; i++)
        {
            if (historicalData[i].Date.Length == fullDatePattern.Length)
                DateTime.TryParseExact(historicalData[i].Date, fullDatePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
            else if (historicalData[i].Date.Length == yearMonthDayPattern.Length)
                DateTime.TryParseExact(historicalData[i].Date, yearMonthDayPattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
            else
                continue;

            // adding date and high
            int ci = historicalChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dt, ibg.HistoricalData()[i].High);
            // adding low
            historicalChart.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[1] = historicalData[i].Low;
            //adding open
            historicalChart.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[2] = historicalData[i].Open;
            // adding close
            historicalChart.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[3] = historicalData[i].Close;

            //historicalChart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
            historicalChart.Series[0].Name = textBoxSymbol.Text;

            if (lastDt == System.DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                lastDt = dt;
                DayBarOpenClose nb = new DayBarOpenClose();
                nb.FirstBar = ibg.HistoricalData()[i];
                chartDateIndexDict[GetYYYYMMDDFromDateTime(dt)] = nb;
            }

            try
            {
                if (dt.Day > lastDt.Day)
                {
                    DayBarOpenClose dboc = chartDateIndexDict[GetYYYYMMDDFromDateTime(lastDt)];
                    dboc.LastBar = ibg.HistoricalData()[i - 1];

                    string seriesName = dt.ToShortDateString();
                    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series s = historicalChart.Series.Add(seriesName);
                    s.Color = Color.Red;
                    s.IsXValueIndexed = true;

                    System.DateTime firstBarDt;
                    System.DateTime lastBarDt;

                    DateTime.TryParseExact(dboc.FirstBar.Date, fullDatePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out firstBarDt);
                    DateTime.TryParseExact(dboc.LastBar.Date, fullDatePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out lastBarDt);

                    Console.WriteLine("FirstDate {0} FirstBar {1} SecondDate {2} SecondBar {3}",
                        firstBarDt.ToString(), dboc.FirstBar.Open, lastBarDt.ToString(), dboc.FirstBar.Open);

                    historicalChart.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(firstBarDt, dboc.FirstBar.Open);
                    historicalChart.Series[seriesName].Points.AddXY(lastBarDt, dboc.FirstBar.Open);
                    historicalChart.Series[seriesName].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;

                    DayBarOpenClose nb = new DayBarOpenClose();
                    nb.FirstBar = ibg.HistoricalData()[i];
                    chartDateIndexDict[GetYYYYMMDDFromDateTime(dt)] = nb;
                    lastDt = dt;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can add Line seires with as many or few points as you want. But the Candlestick datapoints need 4 not 3 y-values! which line throws the error?

Comment: This is a whole new series I want to add to the same chart the candlesticks are in. It is also not a candlestick series, it is a line